# How to get the output like DF3 and DF4 using df1 and df2?

Tags: python, pandas

How to get results like DF3 and DF4 using df1 and df2?

[image]

Comment: Can you post raw data to recreate your dfs, the desired result, your attempts including any errors, and an explanation of the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['A','B','A','D','E'], "age": [1,2,3,3,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['A','B','E','D'], "age": [1,2,3,2]})

df3 = df1.iloc[2:].reset_index(drop=True)
df4 = df2.iloc[2:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
df3

  name  age
0    A    3
1    D    3
2    E    5


df4

  name  age
0    E    3
1    D    2
```

Solution 2:

Remove common rows/ duplicate rows while joining two dataframes